# How to run a DynamoDB script when deploying a serverless project using serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I am using serverless framework to package and deploy my project. One requirement is to load some metadata to one of the DynamoDB table after the table is created. Does the framework provide a mechanism to do this (running a script to load data when the table creation is complete)? I couldn't find anything similar to this.

Comment: are you using AWS lambda?

Comment: @janDro yes I am.

Comment: then shouldn't RDS be separate from your FaaS ? Lambda should just be the function to interact with the DB, but shouldn't be setting up the DB for you right? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you are right I am writing data to Dynamo using lambda functions. My question here is how can I load some ref data to Dynamo during the DEPLOYMENT?! I need to run a dynamo script whenever the corresponding table is created.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`serverless-stack-output` plugin](https://github.com/sbstjn/serverless-stack-output)?  You can use the `handler` type (as opposed to `file`), and run a script post deployment that inserts these values into Dynamo.

Comment: Or you can create a serverless plugin that does :) It sounds its a job for a plugin. Other developers might me thankful :P

Comment: @MikePatrick the serverless-stack-output works very well to load the data to DynamoDB after the stack creation. Thanks.

Comment: @Nisman how'd you do it?

Comment: @MattPark I used the serverless-stack-output as Mike Patrick mentioned in the comments above to run my dynamodb script after the stack is built and its working fine!

Comment: So you used the plugin to get the output, but how did you get cloudstack to run the sql sqtup scripts (or dynamo equiv)?

Comment: So in the serverless.yml file in the Output section you need to provide a handler which is in my case is a javascript function that uses DDB API to write the data to the specified table.